# How to increase left position dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML,

```
<ul>
  <li>List One</li>
  <li>List Two</li>
  <li>List Thre</li>
  <li>List Four</li>
  .......................
</ul>
```

Can I set left value dynamically and increment by 20% on each item?
For example-

```
<ul>
  <li style="left:20%;">List One</li>
  <li style="left:40%;">List Two</li>
  <li style="left:60%;">List Thre</li>
  <li style="left:80%;">List Four</li>
  .......................
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) + [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing or tutorial service

Comment: Well I tried this, but it apply same value on all element.
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).css( "left", "+=20%" );
});

Comment: Is the increment required to be in percentage Can it be in px. Because we will have to back calculate the previous li's left value since their corresponding px value are applied during rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index available in `each()` callback to increment the value:

```js
$( "li" ).each(function(i) {
    var percent = 20 * (i+1) +'%'; 
    $( this ).css( "left", "+=" + percent ); 
});
```

```css
li {position:absolute; top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>List One</li>
  <li>List Two</li>
  <li>List Thre</li>
  <li>List Four</li>

</ul>
```